# is there any way to run python scripts through windows cmd and show python operation and plots in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have python script which consists of plots and text outputs. When I run the script in windows command prompt only text output is showing, is there any way to show plots as well.

The command used for running a script is given below:

```
python.exe D:\2019\Python\web.py
```

When I used `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`, the plots and output are not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can plot in windows cmd. I recommend you to use Jupyter Notebook
[click here](https://jupyter.org)